# Returning object data type from method

Tags: java, arrays

I have some java book and i'm doing exercises. But right now i'm stuck on exercises associated with arrays. i have following exercise:

> Create a CollegeCourse class. The class contains fields for the course ID (for example,
>   “CIS 210”), credit hours (for example, 3), and a letter grade (for example, ‘A’).
>
> Include get() and set()methods for each field. Create a Student class containing an
>   ID number and an array of five CollegeCourse objects. Create a get() and set()
>   method for the Student ID number. Also create a get() method that returns one
>   of the Student’s CollegeCourses; the method takes an integer argument and
>   returns the CollegeCourse in that position (0 through 4). Next, create a set()
>   method that sets the value of one of the Student’s CollegeCourses; the method
>   takes two arguments—a CollegeCourse and an integer representing the
>   CollegeCourse’s position (0 through 4).

I already did data fields and id's and getters from student class. But right now i'm a little confused with this:

> Also create a get() method that returns one
>   of the Student’s CollegeCourses; the method takes an integer argument and
>   returns the CollegeCourse in that position (0 through 4). Next, create a set()
>   method that sets the value of one of the Student’s CollegeCourses; the method
>   takes two arguments—a CollegeCourse and an integer representing the
>   CollegeCourse’s position (0 through 4).

Can anyone point me to the right direction how to resolve this. Because it's array chapter i think it must be resolved doing arrays? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: ok here is my CollegeCourse Class

public class CollegeCourse {

```
String courseID;
int creditHours;
char grade;

public void setCourseId(String id) {

    this.courseID = id;

}

public String getCourse() {

    return courseID;
}


public void setHours(int hours) {

    this.creditHours = hours;
}

public int getHours() {

    return creditHours;

}

public void setGrade(char grade) {

    this.grade = grade;

}
```

}

and here is my student class ( im stuck here):

public class Student {

```
int id;
CollegeCourse[] cc = new CollegeCourse[5];


public void setId(int id) {

    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {

    return id;
}


public void setCollegeCourse(CollegeCourse course, int position) {


    // i'm stuck here


}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: It seems you didn't fully understand the chapter, and arrays are a very basic part of every programming language. I suggest you read the chapter again and try over.

Comment: well i would say i didn't understood what exercise wants me to do. Because English is not my primary language is sometimes hard to understand what it is trying to tell me. =) But thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically its asking you to create a getter/setter for contents of the array;

```
CollegeCourse[] courses...

...

public CollegeCourse getCourse(int index) {
    return courses[index];
}

public void setCourse(int index, CollegeCourse course) {
    courses[index] = course;
}
```

Comment: i think this is it =) i will study this code some more. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So the book is asking you to define some method that allows retrieval of a Course, given an integer.

You might use it like so (not these are just how they are used, not the actual implementation of the methods - i'll leave that to you):

```
CollegeCourse course = Student.get(1);
```

and the set method would be used like this:

```
Student.set(1, new CollegeCourse("CIS 210", 3, "A"));
```

Does that help? It would be helpful if you posted your code to see where you are at.